Need to reformat excel data into an array with blank lines for items not included in the lookup array
Currently I have this formula
=FILTER('CPFR Paste'!H:AK,('CPFR Paste'!G:G="Receipt Plan")*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH('CPFR Paste'!B:B,A2#))))

I am trying to reformat data from the CPFR Paste sheet by matching SKU from a SKU list in array A2# as well as a Measure in 'CPFR Paste'!G:G.
What I would like to have solved is matching the order of array A2# in the final output and matching the number of lines in the final result. If the SKU in A2# is not in the filtered array, then I would like to return a blank row in the result.
TABS in file:
SKU List (notice the order of the skus matters here)

CPFR Paste (Where the data comes from)

Constrained Sales Forecast (Where the constrained sales forecast data should be returned to)

